# Django - ManyToMany field to User return None

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-1.8, django-permissions

that's my model

```
class Permissions(models.Model):
group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
Book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

I implemented a custom save method to set permissions and save Users to a group:

```
   def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super(Permissions,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
    assign_perm('view_Book',self.group, self.book)
    for gen in self.book.books.all():
        assign_perm('view_Genre', self.group, gen)
    for u in self.users.all():
        u.groups.add(self.group)
        u.save()
```

With this i can set permissions but the users ain't get added to the group. Am i missing something?
When i `print(users)` the return is None, or [].
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What are you expecting in users? Did you select some users in the ModelForm?

Comment: Yes. Even if i didn't have selected any user, when i do "print(users)" the return must be the entire user list, because of many to many relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a similar problem and fixed using [m2m_signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#m2m-changed).

Here is a example:

```
def add_users_book_permissions(sender, **kwargs):

   permissions = kwargs['instance']
   for u in permissions.users.all():
       u.groups.add(permission.group)
       u.save()

m2m_changed.connect(add_users_book_permission,Permissions.users.through)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `permission` object just got created therefor he has no users. That's why you get an empty list.

Probably you want to use: `User.objects.all()`, to get all users regardless of the permission.